# How to enhance such piece of code

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm working on some kind of typing tutor now.
I have simple keyboard model written in pure HTML.
Some HTML is here

```
<div class="keyboard">
<div class="keyboardRow"><span class="key" id="q">Q<sub>Й</sub></span>
<span class="key" id="w">W<sub>Ц</sub></span>
<span class="key" id="e">E<sub>У</sub></span>
<span class="key" id="r">R<sub>К</sub></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Then I want to change color of the border of the key that was pressed.
I've create such piece of "trashcode" in Javascript

```
document.onkeypress = checkKeyPress;
function checkKeyPress(e)
{ var KeyID = e.charCode;
  switch (KeyID){
  case 113: pkey = document.getElementById("q");
        pkey.style.borderColor = "red";
        break; 
   case 119: 
   pkey = document.getElementById("w");
   pkey.style.borderColor = "red";
   break; 
   case 101: 
   pkey = document.getElementById("e");
   pkey.style.borderColor = "red";
   break;
```

...............

And so on. As you can see, guys, my question is: How can I avoid the spaghetti "case" statement and write code which is pretty to look and clear to read?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be on  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo on http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uLhyI

```
function checkKeyPress(e) { 
  var KeyID = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode).toLowerCase();
  document.getElementById(KeyID).style.border = "solid red";
}
document.onkeypress = checkKeyPress;
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this could be

```
...
pkey = document.getElementById(String.fromCharCode(KeyID));
pkey.style.backgroundColor = "red";
...
```

This solution translates the key code (such as 115, 119, etc.) into the corresponding character. Since your keys are marked with ID being equal to the key they represent, you simply get the element by id where the id is the letter.

Comment: It means that id's would match to charCode of the key, right?

Comment: Yes. So for example when you hit letter "s", the `KeyID` will be 115 and `String.fromCharCode(115)` returns "s" therefore `document.getElementById("s");`

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using jquery I'd reccomend that. Since javascript excells at event-oriented programming it would be preferable to handle keypresses in an evented way.

It also promotes asynchronous event handling. Which basically means that the user can press multiple keys and the browser won't have to go through that giant switch statement.

Also, the jquery keyboard method provides a `key` value with the string representation of the key that was pressed.. so you can have juse one event handler function through jquery.

[The `keydown` event in the JQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/)

### Example

```
$(document).keydown(function(evt) {
 var selector = '#' + evt.key;
 $(selector).css('border-color', 'red');
});
```

That should work for every key.

Comment: Pure Javascript approach fits to me pretty good.
But anyway thank you for link :)

Comment: It's still good to keep this in mind. You never know when someone will walk up to you and say "HEY! I'll give you $100 if you tell me what the keydown jquery function does"

Comment: So, I'll try to to give proper weigh to your advice in my spare time

Comment: But this code doesn't handle hits on square brackets too :(
It is only shorter, than others samples because of jquery, doc ;)

Answer (score 0):

So, my dears, I've decided to use Keypress library to solve my problem:

http://dmauro.github.io/Keypress/